# How should development process look like for Jenkins pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Our product is using Jenkins pipeline to do automation.  When doing changes to the job configuration, I don't want current running pipeline to be impacted.  So, I would like to have 2 pipeline, for example, Pipeline A and Pipeline B.  A runs all cases, and for development, we just make changes to B.  After B is configured correctly and all jobs are passing, I can switch B as the real in-use pipeline, and then do all configuration change on A.  The problem here is, how can I safely and correctly apply changes that were happened to B to A?  Well, I'm able to access Jenkins master...

Answer (score 0):

So you have few options to choose from:

1. You can create separate Pipeline jobs and define Pipeline scripts
   inside each of them. When `development` version is ready just copy code to `production`.
2. You could create separate Pipeline jobs and use `SCM` to keep Pipeline scripts in separate branches. When `development` version is ready just merge it with `production` branch.

   - You could store your Pipeline configuration alongside your project as `Jenkinsfile`.
   - `Jenkinsfile` allows you to switch easily and is convenient to manage your Pipeline configuration in case of **Multibranch** projects.

Last but not least. Keep in mind [Replay](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/04/14/replay-with-pipeline/) feature, which allows you to validate your modifications more rapidly.